# how get value array of a field in aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation

I have a collection that save information about a movie, this collection name is **Movie**. one of this field is **stars** that save actors that play in a movie. I save **stars** in an array. *now i want write a function with aggregation that can return to me Stars that play in most movies*. Furthermore, I saved stars in User collection. I wrote this function but it is wrong. because it group stars as an array

```
async function starsActMostMovies(){
const res = await Movie.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id : '$stars'
        }
    }
])
return res
}
starsActMostMovies().then(function(result){
console.log(result)})
```

and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150316/how-to-use-of-objectid-in-nodejs) I wrote my database models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should split the array at that field start, so your collection will contain only one star.

Use the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator to perform it. For example:

```
Movie.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$stars'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id : '$stars' 
        }
    }
])
```

After $unwind 'ing $group will perform aggregation per star.
Good luck!