# how to get information of another collection with lookup

Tags: mongoose, aggregation

I have 2 collections: Movie and User. in Movie I saved information about movies such as **stars** who actors that play in movie. i saved this field as an array in Movie collection. now I want to write a query that return stars name. but this name field saved in User collection. how can I extract data from another collection to this collection? I write this function but it's wrong and stars_doc is empty.
this is my function :

```
async function starsActMostMovies(){
const res = await Movie.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$stars'
    }
    ,
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "User",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField : "stars",
            as: "stars_doc"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        $group: {
            _id : '$stars' ,
            count : { $sum : 1}
        }
    }
    ,
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
return res
}
starsActMostMovies().then(function(result){
    console.log(result)})
```

and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150316/how-to-use-of-objectid-in-nodejs) I wrote my database models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your database models I think you may have the incorrect ref string in your  movie schema definition. Inside of your movie schema you have:

```
stars:[{
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'userSchema'
}],
```

but your user model is defined as:

`var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);`

The `ref` in your movie schema needs to refer to the name you give the user model which is in this case is `'user'` not `userSchema`